# Enable HTTPS for AWS hosted multisite domain (with AWS purchased SSL) on already created Load Balancer?

Tags: multisite, ssl

Has anyone with a WP multisite been through this process? I have created the Load Balancer and have a domain (one of the multisite sites) on an EC2 instance.

My load balancer setup looks like this:

[image]

Going to **https://foobar.com** just times out and going to **https://www.foobar.com** just ignores the SSL request. Is there a step I'm missing? Maybe something in **httpd.conf** or **wp-config**?

I'm sure someone has gone through something similar, it would help us all dealing with such an issue. I feel like going with WPEngine would've made much more sense than AWS for an simple WP site :(

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Do these URLs work without the balancers? Are  you trying to put different domains on different boxes? Why?

Answer (score 0):

I am familiar with this situation ... I got out of it like this ... To begin with, in the .htaccess file that lies at the root of the site of your hosting provider - I registered it. At the very end of the file.

```
# END WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?yoursite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !=https
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Then I installed the plugin:
SSL Insecure Content Fixer.
And set the settings in it to “Capture everything” - saved. For two weeks I drove the site with the plugin turned on. Then I deactivated the plugin. And everything became good!

[Here is my working example](https://www.auto-truck.by/)